# Difference between rpart models, one with information split the other with rpart.control

Tags: r, decision-trees, pruning

What is the difference between these two models?

```
bankmodel <- rpart(y ~ ., data = train, method = "class", control = rpart.control(cp = 0))
info.model <- rpart(y~., data = train, parms=list(split="information"))
```

I see one is split using the method="class", and there's a control = rpart.control(cp=0), should the complexity parameter be a different value or is that calculated some way? The info.model has params = list and there's an information split. Is one pre or post pruned and the other not pruned?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]